# Aloha shirts in Portland?

Tags: professionalism, work-environment, company-culture

I currently live and work in the Honolulu area, but I am considering a move to Portland, Oregon for personal reasons.  I work in the IT field (an office setting), so right now it's perfectly appropriate to wear an "aloha" style shirt to work every day.  I'll be looking for the same type of work in the Portland area.  Would it be seen as weird or inappropriate if I wear the same shirts in Portland?  Should I give them all away and buy more "conservative" shirts?

Comment: That would be entirely dependent on the company employing you.

Comment: Maybe hold on to them and see what everybody else is wearing.... but being from Hawaii you'll probably get a pass. :)

Comment: When you're an outsider I find it pays to dress conservatively at least at first. You're under more scrutiny since you're a bit of a novelty for a while. Once you have settled in you will know whether it's appropriate or not.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on the company and the position. I've worked at software companies in Honolulu, Portland, and Seattle where aloha wear was perfectly acceptable for daily work or even interviews. In the summer, I regularly wear shorts and an old aloha shirt to my current job in Seattle. However, other businesses have different standards. Positions in law, medicine, banking, and customer relations sometimes have more formal dress codes. If in doubt, it rarely hurts to ask.

The one area that might be ambiguous would be "business casual". When I lived in Hawaii "business casual" was essentially identical with nice, high end, aloha wear. On the mainland, even in Portland and Seattle, "business casual" usually means khakis, and polo or button down shirts, in conservative colors. A bright aloha print shirt might raise a few eyebrows as too informal, and they may not recognize a high end aloha shirt as any different from one picked up from a thrift store.